# How to launch an app when the screen unlocks?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, screen-lock

I have tried this code but it's not working. Does anybody have any different solution? I have tried many ways like the below one from Stack Overflow but none of them is working.

manifest.xml

```
 <receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
 </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

screenreceiver

```
  public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
         {
            Intent intent = new Intent();  
            intent.setClass(context, ScreenLockActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);          
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: SCREEN_ON or OFF could not able to list into manifest anymore. You should run a foreground service and register `ScreenReceiver` via code, then it will works

Comment: can you please explain it with a code sample ? @AdmiralKunkka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To listen to screen on/off, your app should run by time and register `Broadcast receiver` to OS programmatically.

ScreenOnOffService.java

```
public class ScreenOnOffService extends Service {

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("ScreenOnOffService", "onCreate: ");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
//        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF");
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON");
        registerReceiver(ScreenOnReceiver.newInstance(), intentFilter);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("ScreenOnOffService", "onDestroy: ");
        unregisterReceiver(ScreenOnReceiver.newInstance());
//        startService(new Intent(this,ScreenOnOffService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

ScreenOnReceiver.java

```
public class ScreenOnReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String TAG = "ScreenOn";
    public static volatile ScreenOnReceiver screenOn;

    public static ScreenOnReceiver newInstance() {
        if (screenOn == null) {
            screenOn = new ScreenOnReceiver();
        }
        return screenOn;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("hieuN", "intent: " + intent.getAction());
        // do work. start activity.

    }
}
```

Start service in activity

```
Intent service = new Intent(this, ScreenOnOffService.class);
startService(service);
```

Comment: Except this service would get killed almost immediately, it wouldn't be reliable.  A foreground service would make it more so.  But in the end, there's no real way to assure you can listen to screen on or off reliably anymore.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes. Make service as foreground and nearly un-killable and it will solve the problem.

Comment: its just works when i minimize the app and lock screen.
but when i exit the app completely and also destroy it from minimized it doesn't work @AdmiralKunkka

Comment: @AqibAbbas Because when you swipe it off, the service is killed and thus there's no registered listener.  Its not possible to keep listeneng to this even in that circumstance on modern versions of Android.  Your app needs to be running.

Comment: @AqibAbbas change `ScreenOnReceiver.java` to foreground service, then it still work when you swipe out. Just not work for Chinese phone.